# How to update customized listview on incoming messages..?

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver

Currently am working on a project where text messages from a particular person is stored and displayed. Am using customized list view for displaying the stored messages. Till this part my code is fine. But i need to update my list view when a new messages arrives when the activity is on foreground. Unfortunately the list view only updates the new message when the activity goes to onCreate() method again. I need to update the listview if it is on foreground. Any ideas.....???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your refresh code in onResume() instead of putting it in onCreate(). 
   On every time you get the new message call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method to update the layout

Comment: the message is received on a receiver and am updating listview from activity. how could i call a activity method from receiver. even if refresh code is supplied inside onResume() i need i quit activity for updating. i need to update it while the activity is on foreground..

Comment: register for Broadcast receiver. Whenever there is an update send a broadcast the message from the receiver. Register to BroadcastReceiver in onResume() and unregister in onPause() to update listview only when your app in foreground. On receiving the message in your BroadcastReciever, update the listview.